# Haskell Stack failing to install easyrender

Tags: haskell, package, ghc, cabal, haskell-stack

I have GHC 8.0.2 installed on a Haskell stack, and I need a certain number of packages on it for my project, one being easyrender.

I install it using the following command, which works for all other package installations:

```
stack install easyrender
```

I get the following output:

```
easyrender-0.1.1.2: configure

--  While building package easyrender-0.1.1.2 using:
  /home/nathan/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc --make -odir /tmp/stack5987/easyrender-0.1.1.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup -hidir /tmp/stack5987/easyrender-0.1.1.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup -i -i. -clear-package-db -global-package-db -package-db=/home/nathan/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/8.0.2/pkgdb -package-db=/home/nathan/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/8.0.2/pkgdb -hide-all-packages -package-id=base-4.9.1.0 -package-id=superdoc-0.1.2.5-9gGVGYAJpHrGct376cUN41 -optP-include -optP/tmp/stack5987/easyrender-0.1.1.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup_macros.h /tmp/stack5987/easyrender-0.1.1.2/Setup.hs /home/nathan/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs -main-is StackSetupShim.mainOverride -o /tmp/stack5987/easyrender-0.1.1.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup -threaded
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: /home/nathan/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/easyrender-0.1.1.2.log

[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/stack5987/easyrender-0.1.1.2/Setup.hs, /tmp/stack5987/easyrender-0.1.1.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/Main.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( /home/nathan/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /tmp/stack5987/easyrender-0.1.1.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/StackSetupShim.o )

/home/nathan/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs:3:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Distribution.PackageDescription’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘Cabal-2.0.1.0’.
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘Cabal-1.24.2.0’.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

/home/nathan/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs:4:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Distribution.Simple’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘Cabal-2.0.1.0’.
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘Cabal-1.24.2.0’.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

/home/nathan/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs:5:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Distribution.Simple.Build’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘Cabal-2.0.1.0’.
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘Cabal-1.24.2.0’.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

/home/nathan/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs:6:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Distribution.Simple.Setup’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘Cabal-2.0.1.0’.
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘Cabal-1.24.2.0’.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

/home/nathan/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs:7:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Distribution.Simple.LocalBuildInfo’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘Cabal-2.0.1.0’.
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘Cabal-1.24.2.0’.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Since Cabal seems to be a problem, I tried running `stack install Cabal`, but that doesn't do anything. The log file referenced just says the same thing as the output.

Ideas?
Nathan

Comment: "Cabal seems to be a problem"  the problem is actually that the needed module is "a member of the hidden package..." so don't hide the package - list it explicitly as a dependency for easyrender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such problems with cabal-install:

```
% cabal install easyrender
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading superdoc-0.1.2.5...
Configuring superdoc-0.1.2.5...
Building superdoc-0.1.2.5...
Installed superdoc-0.1.2.5
Downloading easyrender-0.1.1.2...
Configuring easyrender-0.1.1.2...
Building easyrender-0.1.1.2...
Installed easyrender-0.1.1.2
```

So I'm guessing this is an issue with stack handling non-simple builds in a different manner.  Namely, cabal-install seems to assume Cabal is a dependency of the setup.hs while stack does not.

Just to check, I tried and could produce your same issue but adding `Cabal` to the `setup-depends:` line of the `easyrender.cabal` made it work fine.

Comment: Where would I find `easyrender.cabal` such that I can add `Cabal` to `setup-depends`?

Comment: Well using cabal-install it's `cabal unpack easyrender ; cd easyrender* ; vi easyrender.cabal`.  Stack probably has some similar unpack abilities or you can download the package from the repo.

Comment: Ok, I added `Cabal == 2.*` to the line you mentioned, but nothing seems to change. Did I do that wrong?

Comment: I mean it now looks like this `setup-depends: base >= 4.5 && < 5, Cabal == 2.*, superdoc == 0.1.*` I even did `stack update` to be sure, but the output is the same.

Comment: and you did `stack install` not `stack install easyrender` right?

Comment: `stack install` returns `Error parsing targets: The project contains no local packages (packages not marked with 'extra-dep')` I assume this means I'm supposed to somehow flag the easyrender.cabal file as being extra-dep, but how?

Comment: Ok, I figured out I had to add `easyrender-0.1.1.2` in the `packages` array in `stack.yaml`, thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the easyrender package description.  Note that cabal-install's "new-build" encounters the same problem.  See my comment on this stack issue: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3560#issuecomment-344075524

Workaround is as described by Thomas's answer, and also in the issue at https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3560#issuecomment-343980627

The next stack release will emit a warning about this circumstance, which should reduce confusion in the future.

Unfortunately, easyrender does not have an issue tracker, it appears to only have a hackage page.  I have emailed the author requesting that he fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the info